# Does anyone have a full explanation of the riddle in The Cursed Child

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* there is a riddle. While I can get a lot of it (indeed, a fair amount of it is explained by the characters themselves), I'm less confident about other bits, particularly the last third of the riddle. So, does anybody have a complete breakdown of the riddle?

> The first is the fourth, a disappointing mark
> You'll find it in parked but not in park.  [...]
> The second is the less fair of those that walk on two legs.
> Grubby, hairy a disease of the egg.
> And the third is both a mountain to climb and a route to take.  [...]
> A turn in the city, a glide through a lake.
>
> (*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* - pp.89-90 - Little, Brown - Act One, Scene Nineteen)

Comment: I'm a bit stumped by "*A turn in the city, a glide through a lake*"

Comment: For me the bigger riddle is why Hermione left **the most dangerous artifact in the whole world** protected by riddles that a child could answer.

Comment: @Valorum perhaps in admiration of Dumbledore, who once did the same with an item granting infinite wealth and immortality?

Comment: @TenthJustice - The riddles were only one part. Credit to Dumbledore, he did have stronger protections.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### De

- *The first is the fourth* **[letter of the alphabet]**, *a disappointing mark* **[D for [Dreadful](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dreadful)]**
- *You'll find it in park**ed** but not in park* = **[Self-explanatory. The letters *D and E* are not found in the *word* park]**

### Men

- *The second is the less fair of those that walk on two legs* = **Women are known as [the fair sex](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78534/origin-of-fairer-sex). Men are, by intimation the less fair.**
- *Grubby, hairy, a disease of the egg* = **[Hermione is suggesting that the eggs which result in male births are *diseased*]**.

### Tors

- *And the third is both a mountain to climb* **[Another word for a mountain is a '[tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(rock_formation))]**' *and a route to take* **[as in *'guided [tours](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tour)*'].**
- *A turn in the city, a glide through a lake* = **[These just seem to be examples of places on which you could be taken for a guided tour].**

---

> **DELPHI/HERMIONE** (effusively): *Men! De-men . . . tors. We need to find a book on dementors.* (The bookcase pulls her in.) *Albus!*
>
> **ALBUS/RON:** *Delphi! What is going on?*
>
> **SCORPIUS/HARRY:** *Concentrate, Albus. Do what she said. Find a book on dementors and be very careful.*

Comment: @Valorum -  Isn't the final line just more on 'tours'? Visit a city or travel across a lake?

Comment: @thrugog - Very possibly.  Each of the stanzas were in two-line couplets. I've edited your suggestion in, but I'm not 100% convinced.

Comment: glide may be used as a symbol for moving dementors..

Answer (score 0):

The explanation above is correct. However, the third part is just “tor”, not “tors”. It refers to a singular mountain or a singular route to take. The fourth part is simply “s”, like an s-turn, and hand signal like an s you’d give to sign, something gliding. The breakdown is: De-Men-Tor-S (four parts, same as riddle)

Comment: Can you provide any evidence to back this up?

Answer (score -2):

*The first is the fourth, a disappointing mark
You'll find it in parked but not in park.*

Hermione in the books is very strict about grades. She considered herself a failure even when she got "Outstanding" in all of her other classes and "Exceeds Expectations" in Defense Against the Dark Arts. Of course she'd find a D disappointing.
As for the second line there, *that's* a dead giveaway.

Comment: Whilst partial answers are fine this mostly elaborates on the easiest lines in the riddle, and doesn't really actually say what the answer is. Could you [edit] this to be a bit clearer and also, hopefully, expand it to answer about the other parts of the riddle as well?